# macro/vba code to copy down formula from range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula in cells D4 to L4 and I would like to copy them down to the last row of column A that has data in it.

Following code does work only for single column but I need range of columns (D4:L4). Can someone please help me out how to change following code.

```
Sub copyFormula() 
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, m As Long 
    Set r1 = Range("N2") 
    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    Set r2 = Range("N3:N" & m) r1.Copy r2 
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Move the last statement into its own row.

```
    Set r2 = Range("N3:N" & m)
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

That way the code runs fine from a Sheet module. If you want to run it from a normal module, you will need to qualify the ranges, for example like this:

```
Sub copyFormula()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, m As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r1 = ws.Range("N2")
    m = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r2 = ws.Range("N3:N" & m)
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```